# Re-enabling Third Party Entries in sources.list through SSH (remotely)

Tags: apt, server, 20.04, ssh, software-sources

Wondering how you can do this? Upgraded from version 16(.?) to 20.04.3 LTS, and I got this message, I use it for a fair bit of port-forwarding and streaming and etc, using it as a media server, and I'm just wondering how to do this?

I didn't initially set this up, but yeah I am curious as it does say

> Some third-party entries in your sources.list were disabled. You can re-enable them after the upgrade with the 'software-properties' tool or your package manager.

A lot of people say to go to the Ubuntu Software Centre, but I think you can only do that on the machine itself, the other thing I tried was nano'ing into /etc/apt/sources.list but I can't see really any third party entries in there.

Anyone know how to re-enable them remotely?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to visit `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` directory, locate `*.list` files here and find lines ending with *`# disabled on upgrade to focal`*.

Be careful - some third-party repositories may not have packages for current Ubuntu versions.
For example uncommenting lines like *`"# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/notepadqq-team/notepadqq/ubuntu focal main # disabled on upgrade to focal"`* will lead to 404 error (*does not have a Release file.*) on next `sudo apt-get update` as this PPA does not have packages for 20.04 LTS (*focal* fossa).
So safe method is to visit *http://ppa.launchpad.net/notepadqq-team/notepadqq/ubuntu* link by web-browser and check the existence of *`dists/focal`* folder here. If *`focal`* folder exists in *`dists`* folder then you can uncomment line safely and then run `sudo apt-get update` followed by `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` to get upgrades with new dependencies.

Comment: How do you know if its compatible with the current version? But thankyou so much for your reply!

Comment: See updated answer above.